# CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR doesn't work with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I can configure a really simple inline CKEditor instance and add the CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR in the config. But it doesn't work, the editor still breaks with `<p>` elements. Why?

```
CKEDITOR.inline(el.get(0),
{
   enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adrianrosca/8xykrxwu/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the editor is created by auto-inline feature of CKEditor, which [can be disabled](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-disableAutoInline):

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoinline = true;
```

If you don't disable that option, your calls to `CKEDITOR.inline` won't work, because the editor is already created.

You can also use [`editor.setActiveEnterMode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setActiveEnterMode) to change editor's current behavior for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You should also note that `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` mode is [**NOT** recommended](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_best_practices-section-use-enter-mode-p). If you do it to control paragraph spacing, you should use stylesheets instead.